# UIPickerView alternative for iphone something like combo box?

Tags: ios, ios4, combobox

Are there any alternative controls instead of `UIPickerView` in **XCode**. If yes, how do they work? Can anyone suggest an alternative for `UIPickerView`?

Comment: are you trying to create a list of choices for users to pick one? If so, in iPhone, one way is to use the `UITableVeiw`

Comment: As comment by @Steven, you can user `UITableView` with choices, you can give little animation to show/hide your `UITableView`. It can be looks like drop down of your choise!

Comment: oh thanks... let me try as u said....

Answer (score 0):

You can see one in action if you download the free One Stop Plus app (women's clothes), drill down on the products until you get a view with Color, Size, etc. Tapping those buttons animates a table out of the button, with choices. Selecting one causes the table to animate back into the button. If you like that post a comment to this answer and I can tell you how to do it.

Comment: Actually. I am new to this iOS development field.So please help me as u can,Sir.....

Comment: Well, that's a problem. Maybe you can find an open source class that does this. Its not easy for a noobie to do. Essentially you create a small table when the button is pressed, you animate the table's frame so it appears to pop out of the button, you implement all the UITableView delegate/data source methods, then set the frame to a 0 height frame when done then delete the table.

Comment: can u  suggest any nice referring material or site so that i could get some idea in this...

Comment: These are the techniques you learn after a long time developing. If you have the time try to do it yourself, and post code and questions as you do it. You can read up on how to get a button action method, how to create a small table and use its delegate, how to use UIView to animate the table. I believe what that app did was put a transparent view just under the table, so that it could use a gesture recognizer to intercept taps outside the table to dismiss it. If you do this it will take you several days, you will learn a lot doing it. This is how most of us have learned to do these things.

Answer (score 0):

With iPhone interface, it is not feasible to enable a Combo box like a website. (I believe even Apple Guidelines would say not to do it). What you need to do is the use the `UITableView` to enable users to pick one option.

One thing you can do is decide whether you want to have the choice in a view shared with other controls. OR if your list if too long you can chose to push in a new view with only the choices on them and when a user selects one, the view will pop back one level.

Here is a screen shot of what i mean (maybe not the best example out there):

[image]

Comment: But if we want to add our country name or some things from a list of objects.. then what we need to use in iPhone Applications

Comment: What you are trying to do is not for a beginner. I would recommend taking the next few days learning about iOS development. Basically, almost everything you know about web programming, you can throw them out the window. What you can bring in, is your programming logic. iOS programming works quite differently. Look at this article, it provides basic and quite comprehensive tutorial for beginners: http://maniacdev.com/2011/02/ios-beginner-screencasts-xcode-and-objective-c-from-the-start/